# Was able to resolve modules with Polymer 3, but not with Lit Element

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, lit-html, lit

I have always been able to use https://github.com/nodecg/express-transform-bare-module-specifiers with Polymer 3 and browser sync. But now  I am getting errors with the set up and lit element

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "lit". Relative references must  start with either "/", "./", or "../".

It is for the following files being requested:

```
/node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js
/node_modules/lit/polyfill-support.js
/app/main-app.js
/node_modules/lit/polyfill-support.js.map
```

What has changed? A module is a module....this should work with lit element as it did with P3

Please do not recommend wds, while it is a great tool it does not fit my use case

My browser-sync config that works with Polymer 3 modules but not Lit:

```
const app = express();
const bs = require('browser-sync').create();
app.use('*', transformMiddleware());

bs.init({
  server: true,
  notify: false,
  "files": [

  ],
  middleware: [
    proxyMiddleware,
    historyApiFallback(),
  ],
  port: 4000,
  ui: false,
});
```

Comment: As you've said the library being used shouldn't really affect this. I wonder if the response for the file serve is not getting a matching 'content-type' and skipping the transform here https://github.com/nodecg/express-transform-bare-module-specifiers/blob/7c67eec7038adf973fbe4242f60d2aacb3a3fa0f/src/compile-middleware.ts#L42-L50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I did not have app placed in the `middleWare` array....
Placing in `app` in the array fixed the issue and now browser sync works great with lit element and express-transform-bare-module-specifiers.

```
const historyApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const transformMiddleware =
  require('express-transform-bare-module-specifiers').default;

const app = express();
const bs = require('browser-sync').create();

app.use(transformMiddleware());

bs.init({
  server: true,
  notify: false,
  "files": [
    'app/**/**/**/*',
    'app/**/**/*',
    'app/**/*',
    'app/*',
  ],
  middleware: [
    historyApiFallback(),
    app,
  ],
  port: 4000,
  ui: false,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try in browser-sync config:

```
app.use('*', transformMiddleware({
  transform: (code, id) => {
    if (id.endsWith('.js')) {
      return code.replace(/from 'lit'/g, 'from \'lit/index.js\'');
    //return code.replace(/from 'lit'/g, `from 'lit/index.js'`);
    }
    return code;
  }
}));
```

Another option:

```
const app = express();
const bs = require('browser-sync').create();
app.use('*', transformMiddleware());

bs.init({
  server: true,
  notify: false,
  "files": [

  ],
  middleware: [
    proxyMiddleware,
    historyApiFallback(),
    expressTransformBareModuleSpecifiers
  ],
  port: 4000,
  ui: false,
});
```

Comment: `transform` is not listed in the docs. I also tried it but nothing ever executes in the `transform` function.